# android. Autofocused textview on activity startup

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

I have a activity, which view have a several EditText components.

When activity starts, the first of EditTexts became focused and keyboard appears. I would like to avoid this 'feature' ( I mean I want that there will be no popup keyboard after activity started)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a LinearLayout (I dunno if other kinds of Layout's will work). Set the attributes `android:focusable="true"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`.

```
<!-- Dummy item to prevent AutoCompleteTextView from receiving focus -->
<LinearLayout
    android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="0px"/>

<!-- :nextFocusUp and :nextFocusLeft have been set to the id of this component
     to prevent the dummy from receiving focus again -->
<AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:nextFocusUp="@+id/text" android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/text"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

to the activity element in your manifest.